# Trying to dynamically connect in Powershell to nearest Exchange Server

Tags: powershell, exchange-server

New-PSSession wants a -ConnectionURI of an explict Exchange server.  I don't want to hardcode a name in the script (we have 32 servers), and furthermore I want it to select an exchange that is in the same datacenter.

I want a solution similar to Get-ADDomainController -Discover -GetClosestSite   But it seems I'm hoping for too much.

I suppose I can pull the members of cn=Exchange Install Domain Servers and do some site dependent ranking on them.

Looking for best practices.

Update Edit: 9/26  I have achieved a solution.  It may be site specific, but I'll share below in an answer to show the final code.  The answer provided by postanote provided pointers that helped me move forward.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no official documented best practices for PowerShell in general (there are too many variables in the mix, but some have put their thoughts in the topic , for example, this one - https://github.com/PoshCode/PowerShellPracticeAndStyle ) or for what you are asking for from Microsoft.

As for you point here:

> I suppose I can pull the members of cn=Exchange Install Domain Servers
>   and do some site dependent ranking on them.

This is not something new, or tricky, so you can do this.

I have code in my personal library  that I use that does this as well as for other doing resources, so I never have to hardcode server names for Exchange, SQL, DC, etc.

There are several blogs (that have been out there for a while now) on the topic with sample code to use as is or tweak as needed, which is why I asked what you've searched for.

One of those blog examples of how to do this is here:

https://use-powershell.blogspot.com/2012/12/find-exchange-servers-in-domain.html

The examples provided:

> 1. an active directory  user with mailbox will have 2 attributes (msExchHomeServerName and homemdb) that will contain the name of the
>      mailbox server that has his mailbox - once conected to one server you
>      can use exchange console to find the rest of them;

```
Get-ADUser samaccountname -Properties msExchHomeServerName, homemdb |Select-Object msExchHomeServerName, homemdb |Format-List
```

> 2. active directory computer type objects contain "exchange" word in servicePrincipalName attribute; you can use only your
>      organizational unit that contain your servers if you have one to
>      narrow your search:

```
Get-ADComputer -Filter * -SearchBase 'OU= SERVERS, DC=domain_name,DC=net' -Properties * | Where-Object {$_.serviceprincipalname -like '*exchange*'} |select-object  name
```

> 3. active directory configuration partition contain information about exchange servers in domain; you can search for objects of class
>      msExchExchangeServer:

```
Get-ADObject -LDAPFilter "(objectClass=msExchExchangeServer)" –SearchBase "CN=Configuration,DC=domainname,DC=net" | Select-Object  name
```

> or you can list all objects from "CN=Servers,CN=First Administrative Group,CN=Administrative Groups,CN=INTERNAL,CN=Microsoft
>   Exchange,CN=Services,CN=Configuration,DC=domainname,DC=net" using
>   powershell or ADSI Edit console;

```
Get-ADObject -Filter * -SearchBase "CN=Servers,CN=First Administrative Group,CN=Administrative Groups,CN=INTERNAL,CN=Microsoft Exchange,CN=Services,CN=Configuration,DC=domainname,DC=net" -SearchScope onelevel
```

Or this post:

https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/ie/en-US/94d89161-9dfb-48fc-b307-2f0e1320c9dc/how-to-find-file-servers-and-exchange-servers-in-ad-

Example:

```
dsquery * "cn=Configuration,dc=MyDomain,dc=com" -Filter "(objectCategory=msExchExchangeServer)"
```

Or if you are really trying to get an Exchange server in  given site, then this to already exists. See this GitHub source:

https://github.com/mikepfeiffer/PowerShell/blob/master/Get-ExchangeServerInSite.ps1

The sample provided is:

```
function Get-ExchangeServerInSite {
    $ADSite = [System.DirectoryServices.ActiveDirectory.ActiveDirectorySite]
    $siteDN = $ADSite::GetComputerSite().GetDirectoryEntry().distinguishedName
    $configNC=([ADSI]"LDAP://RootDse").configurationNamingContext
    $search = new-object DirectoryServices.DirectorySearcher([ADSI]"LDAP://$configNC")
    $objectClass = "objectClass=msExchExchangeServer"
    $version = "versionNumber>=1937801568"
    $site = "msExchServerSite=$siteDN"
    $search.Filter = "(&($objectClass)($version)($site))"
    $search.PageSize=1000
    [void] $search.PropertiesToLoad.Add("name")
    [void] $search.PropertiesToLoad.Add("msexchcurrentserverroles")
    [void] $search.PropertiesToLoad.Add("networkaddress")
    $search.FindAll() | %{
        New-Object PSObject -Property @{
            Name = $_.Properties.name[0]
            FQDN = $_.Properties.networkaddress |
                %{if ($_ -match "ncacn_ip_tcp") {$_.split(":")[1]}}
            Roles = $_.Properties.msexchcurrentserverroles[0]
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your comments... You say the problem is not new, but I had not successfully found anything relevant via uncountable Google and StackExchange searches.    I will look at your links.     Another wrinkle in my scenario, is this is a pre-onboarding situation.   We have not created the mailbox for the user yet.  So any approach based on looking up an existing user isn't useful either.  We are trying to run some sizing metrics to attempt to balance which mailbox we will create the user in.

Comment: No worries it happens. Most of the time, it's just cycling thru parts of strings to get the hits you are after. Mostly, you hit partials, then you have to expand on that. When I first started trying to do this sort of use case a few years back, that's what I had to do to get the ideas of what others had already tried, failed and were successful with. I never got full answers initially of course, but changing the question around, got me what I needed, to resolve my needs. The ones provided in my response are the normal samples I pass on to my teammates, and customers trying to do this thing.

Comment: As for you item here: "We have not created the mailbox for the user yet. So any approach based on looking up an existing user isn't useful either. We are trying to run some sizing metrics to attempt to balance which mailbox we will create the user in.", then that last block of code should get you where you want to be.

Answer (score 0):

I'm accepting postanote's answer as being most helpful.

In the end, I created a solution that may be site and Exchange install specific, but it does illustrate another technique.

My constraints that were different than most other solutions I found and include; that the given user did not currently have a mailbox on the system. Hence the code beyond this snippet will gather some data, then select a specific database.

I discovered that the Exchange server version we have installed, creates some records in "CN=Exchange Install Domain Servers,CN=Microsoft Exchange System Objects,"  In particular, the Members attribute has a list of servers.
I extracted that list, sorted it by Site (local to front), and then resolved the FQDN to form a URI to connect.

```
Function Connect-Exchange {
     #  Find servers list, then sort by name given what site we are running in:  SITE1 = Ascending , SITE2 = Descending
     $ADSite = (Get-ADDomainController).Site
     if ($ADSite -like "SITE1*") { $descOrder =  $true } else { $descOrder = $false }
     $exchSession = $null                                     
     $ExchServersDN = "CN=Exchange Install Domain Servers,CN=Microsoft Exchange System Objects,DC=example,DC=com”
     $ExchServers = (Get-ADObject -Identity $($ExchServersDN) -Properties Member).Member | Sort-Object -Descending:$descOrder 

     # Iterate through Exchange server list until connection succeeds
     $i = 0;
     while ((-Not $exchSession) -and ($i -lt $ExchServers.Count)) { 
        $ExchServerURI = "http://" + (Get-ADObject -Identity $ExchServers[$i] -Properties dNSHostName).dnsHostName + "/Powershell"
        $exchSession = New-PSSession -ConfigurationName Microsoft.Exchange -ConnectionURI $ExchServerURI  -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue
        If (-Not $exchSession)  { $i++ }
        else {                                                                 
            Import-PSSession $exchSession -DisableNameChecking | Out-Null
        }
     }
     return $exchSession
}
```